# jQuery selector by form index and input name

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Take the following page with two forms with different classes but each form has an input with the same name.

```
<form class='first_form'>
 <input name='test' value='1' />
</form>
<form class='second_form'>
 <input name='test' value='3'/>
</form>
```

I can get the form index and I know the name of the input but I do not know the index of the input.

Is there a way to chain a selector with the form index and the input name to get the value?

I have tried chaining but nothing seems to work

```
var inputName = 'test';
Var formIndex = 1;

$('*[name="' + inputName + '"]' +' ' + '$("form").eq(' + formIndex + ')').val();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/4arznx79/1/)

```
var formIndex=0;
var inputName="txtbox";
vall= $("form:eq("+ formIndex+") input[name= "+ inputName +" ]").val();
alert(vall);
```

your order was wrong

Comment: This isn't even a valid selector.

Comment: It should be `:eq`, And `*` is unnecessary.

Comment: *"Why downvotes ????"* Dude, your original answer was wrong for the 14 minutes it sat there.

Comment: @jQueryAngryBird one of the interesting things in SO is that after someone downvotes answer, he rarely comes back to upvote it, even if answer was corrected. Maybe someone supposes, that answer's owner has no second chance. Nevertheless, you still have +16 reputation.

Comment: @Regent  ,check fiddle , you can do +1 its correct answer

Comment: Thanks for the help worked perfectly. It is always nice to have other eyes and minds.

Answer (score 3):

You can access the form's element directly within the DOM using either of:

```
document.forms[formIndex]
document.forms[formName]
```

You can then reference an input element by `name` using:

```
document.forms[formIndex][inputName]
document.forms[formName][inputName]
```

Then just wrap it in `$(...)` to get yourself a jQuery collection. In your case:

```
var inputName = 'test',
    formIndex = 1;

$(document.forms[formIndex][inputName]);
```

I imagine this is by far the most performant way, and it's readable too.

To add a little detail, `document.forms` is an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) of all [`HTMLFormElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement)s within a document. And given any `HTMLCollection` or `HTMLFormElement` you can access named elements within them as properties.

Answer (score 2):

Untested, but could you do:

```
$('form:nth-of-type(1) input[name="test"]').val();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("form:nth-child("+formIndex+") input[name='"+inputName+"']").val();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do in a more clever way:

```
var fieldName = 'test';
var formId = '.first_form'
$('form'+formId+' input[name='+fieldName+']).val()
```

Instead of index, use named selectors, like id or class. It will help you in the future find the correct form (when you will have more than 5, it will be hard to count witch one you are looking at :) )
But that is too complex:)

I would propose something like this:

```
 var currentForm = $('form'+formId);
 currentForm//here you can put a log into console if element has not been found and find that bug sooner.
 currentForm.find('input[name='+fieldName+']').val()
```

Comment: Ech, more programitic way:P But should work. Secondly you are missing type of your inputs. I presume it was text.

Comment: **formId** = '**.first_form**' - are you sure setting jQuery class selector string to variable, which states to be ID, is good (or clever, or whatever)? :)

Comment: I agree it is a bad idea, but in this example class was added to each form. So I don;t want to make too big changes. Ofcourse Id is the only proper way to identiffy forms. My code works with both-I just wanted to present a way of solving this issue in another way, not by index....